# Notepad++ custom language calltips autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++, xbase

I am trying to setup calltips functionality for *Alaska XBase++* language in Notepad++, but I don't manage to get it working.

I read [Npp's how to edit config files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files), I made a user-defined language called **alaska**, and created **alaska.xml** file and put it into *.\plugins\APIs*.

This is the XML code i tried:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <Autocomplete>
        <KeyWord name="sample" func="yes">
            <Overload retVal="void" descr="Sample description">
                <Param name="filename string"/>
            </Overload>
        </KeyWord>
    </Autocomplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Is there anything I am missing in code or outside it? Do I have to install it in some way aside from putting file in *.\plugins\APIs*? I also tried defining *sample* as a keyword in user-defined language window with no result in calltip (as a function).

PS: I made sure autocomplete options are enabled in *Settings->Preferences* (in fact it works for built-in languages), and I set *alaska* as current used language (and I get *sample* formatted as configured in style configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer myself.

After checking that non-function keywords would work with no problem, I tried to completely define an `<Environment>`, even though in Npp docs they say it can be omitted.

> A small example of how the XML file is built is given above. NotepadPlus, AutoComplete and Environment are singleton elements,
>   there should be only one of each, and all of them should be present
>   for correctness, **although it is allowed to remove the <Environment>
>   element.** Doing so will default all values to the ones given in the
>   above example.
>
> Any attribute can be omitted, and the <Environment> tag as well. **The practice is not recommended though**.

This is the complete tag:

```
<Environment ignoreCase="yes" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal="" additionalWordChar = ":"/>
```

And just in case I made sure i forgot no attributes.